# How do I properly setup multi band pass filters in Audiokit?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, audiokit

I would like to setup many band pass filters in AudioKit, to separate a sound source into many bands, each for further processing down the bus/chain.

AudioKit has nodes in a sequence or bus.  Each node has input, does something, and output.  For the graphic EQ [[1]](http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Effects/Graphic%20Equalizer/), the example passes each band's node to the next band's node of the EQ.  But, for a band-pass *filter*, I would assume that each band pass filter node would have the *same* input.  Otherwise, only the passband would pass to the next band pass filter which would then find nothing for itself to pass...

Say I have band pass filter 1 at 1000 Hz with bandwidth of 1000, band pass filter 2 at 2000 Hz with bandwidth of 1000, etc.  If filter 2's input was filter 1's output, filter 2's output would be nothing.

I believe this is what I want:

```
              / band pass filter 1 --> more processing...
sound source -> band pass filter 2 --> more processing...
              \ band pass filter 3 --> more processing...
```

vs

```
sound source -> band pass filter 1 -> band pass filter 2 ...
```

Right?

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely the first one, you are correct.